# I need some basic help installing ubuntu dual boot windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning, windows-10

I'm facing some difficulties installing Ubuntu in dual-boot with 10.

This is my actual partition schematic:

[image: Volume manager screenshot]

How can I install Linux?

Comment: Sorry, but there are, like, **thousands** of Ubuntu installation tutorials around the web (including some tens right here in AskUbuntu). A quick google search should lead yout o Ubuntu installation and even post-installation.

Comment: Have you looked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Specifically what difficulties are you facing?

Comment: It looks more like a BIOS/MBR install, not new UEFI. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Concerning Dennis's link, that's to a page describing a UEFI-based installation; but the posted partition layout has no ESP, so the computer almost certainly uses BIOS, not UEFI. Thus, it's *not* a duplicate of that question. That said, Eduardo's quite correct that the Internet is littered with tutorials covering this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to install Ubuntu along side windows.Please do a brief search on google for it. But you can refer below points to achieve so

- Choose one drive where you want to install Ubuntu ( Since Ubuntu doesn't require much of space , you can choose the drive which is of the minimum space.`20 to 30` GB will be enough.
- Since Ubuntu can read `NTFS` file system, you won't require to format any other drive.You can always store and access your data from Ubuntu in any windows ( `NTFS`)  drive
- The drive that you will choose for Ubuntu installation withh be converted into ext* format ,which is not readable by Windows.
- Once to do the installation, on restart you will be welcomed by Ubuntu boot load screen `since it has high priority` , there you can choose for your desire OS.

Comment: My problem is with Windows 10.
It doesn't allow me to use some spaces.
If I shrink my D:\ . Then on the setup it appears " unusable " and I'm not able to use.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please never tell people to "google for it".  **That is not an answer!**

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW Sure sir I will keep that in mind from now onwards. :)

Comment: Some questions are so basic or common that "Google for it" *is* an appropriate response. That said, the extra issue identified by marco in the first comment for this question is more specific, and deserves reference to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632452/where-can-i-install-ubuntu-if-i-have-4-primary-partitions) question and answer here.