# What windows partition do I delete to free up two partitions for ubuntu root and /home partitions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu on my old laptop. I've been using it in a VM and want to put my laptop to good use. My drive already has 3 partitions and when I try to make the two partitions on ubuntu install it says unusable space. These are the three used partitions in windows: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGIHS.png). Can I remove any of these and if I can how?

Comment: No. You will need to create an extra partition in the 736 GB of unallocated space (see lower right corner).

Comment: @Jos What do I do with the extra partition?

Comment: Well, install Ubuntu in it? BTW it's easier if you boot from a live media and install Ubuntu from there, including creating a new partition. From the desktop, choose Install and when it asks where you want to install Ubuntu choose "Something else".

Comment: @Jos my drive can only support two partitions and I want to make seperate home and root partitions

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/810390/unallocated-space-for-ubuntu-shown-as-unusable-rather-than-free-space

Comment: @Jos the post says delete one partition. My question is what partition do I delete?

Comment: I wouldn't advise you to touch the existing partitions. They might contain Windows data for all we know.

Comment: You don't need to delete any partition. Instead, create an `extended` partition in the unallocated space. Inside the extended partition you can then create as much logical partitions as you need.

Comment: @Jos oh, I actually understand what to do thanks