# How is it possible for my multi-distro system to have more than 4 primary partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I have a multi distro laptop (Ubuntu MATE / Mint Cinnamon / Debian) (32-bit Inspiron 6400 2Gb ram 320GB WD HDD) that ignores the alleged limit of 4 primary partitions. I have 15 and counting.

I'm new to modern Linux and am having a play. I last had a play back in the 90s with GNU Slackware I also have an old Acer 64-bit desktop which will only allow 4 primary partitions. I might try loading another 2 distros on to see if the 5th one boosts. Any ideas why this one machine allows over 4 primary partitions and the other does not?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr/629819

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I install ubuntu if I have 4 primary partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632452/where-can-i-install-ubuntu-if-i-have-4-primary-partitions) Rod Smith's answer.

Comment: In summary, either the drive is GPT (no limit) or if MBR you have extended (logical) partitions.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably on [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition scheme as are all modern Linux. This ignores the partition limit the old [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition scheme set. GPT will also allow you to make bigger partitions than MBR.

https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/

(depending on the language or your os) to verify this you can run :

```
LANG=C && sudo fdisk -l | grep Disklabel
```

in a terminal.

you'll get:

```
Disklabel type: gpt
Disklabel type: gpt
```

Comment: You could add using `sudo fdisk -l | grep Disklabel` to be sure.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142812/temporarily-change-language-for-terminal-messages-warnings-errors) on how to change the output of a single command "temporairement"  **;-)**

Comment: that's very useful @Fabby !

Comment: And on a system that has French installed but has as a default English, use `LANGUAGE=fr sudo fdisk --list`